# No search results at all in the iOS App Store

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

I've got iPad 3 with iOS 7.0.2.

I can't find anything using search option in App Store. No matter what I search for - even well known apps. I've got internet connection, no special search filters. It's been going on for days. I tried restarting the tablet, turning internet on and off. No success.

I'll be very thankful for any ideas how to solve it.

Comment: Try basic troubleshooting steps: quit the app store and relaunch it, turn wifi off and back on again, reboot your iPad, check if wifi in general is working (try a web search?).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however as I've written above I checked all those things already. :-)

Comment: does searching up an app on Google (like "Weather Underground iOS app") then viewing the iTunes.com page in safari, then opening that up in the App Store work? I want to see if an app description page will load up in the app store app. Or try clicking on this link https://appsto.re/us/UjIDy.i and seeing if it'll open up in the app store.

Comment: Yes, going into App Store from a link to an app works as expected. I can also browse categories normally. It's just the search that returns nothing.

Comment: Also is it normal that I'm stuck with selecting either `iPad only` or `Iphone only` option? Why can't I choose both? Sometimes I really don't care about that and have to search twice in both settings.

Comment: Yes. That's normal. Does clicking on a suggested search work? Do those even show up?

Comment: Yes, suggested searches show up, and searching for them works as well...

Comment: I really want to see what you're doing when you search for apps. Do you mind just filming your iPad screen with a spare iPhone (or by plugging into your Mac if you're super fancy) while you search for an app so I can see what's going on?

Comment: Ok, I'll make a screen recording and post it here when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that there are no stray characters in the Search box? Try clicking the `x` at the far right of the Search box and repeating your search.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. :-(